# bind problems with radio input in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Got a binding issue

Excerpt from html code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td haschildren="true"><input id="Grubbel_0" type="radio" name="Grubbel_0" value="0"></td>
        <td haschildren="true"><input id="Grubbel_1" type="radio" name="Grubbel_1" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<img src="img.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
```

Some jQuery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Check radiobuttons when clickin on a parent table cell
        $("td[haschildren='true']").click(function () {
            $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
        });

        // What happens when a radiobutton is changed
        $('*[haschildren="true"] input:radio').bind('change', function () {
            // This does not work when clicking the td boxes
        });
    });
</script>
```

The bind('change'... works when I click directly on the radio box but not when I click on the td although the radiobox gets checked.

Im using jQuery 1.5.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Check radiobuttons when clickin on a parent table cell
    $("td[haschildren='true']").click(function () {
        $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true).trigger('change');
    });

    // What happens when a radiobutton is changed
    $('*[haschildren="true"] input:radio').bind('change', function () {
        // This does not work when clicking the td boxes
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually no, sorry for that my code didn't have that error I just missed that when writing the example here at SO.

Comment: Try the code, have added trigger so it should fire the change method for you and it should work.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the has children selector but I was able to do it with class names.

Comment: Also, it now means that the radio change event is triggered twice if you click the radio itself.

Answer (score 0):

A small syntax error change `$("td[haschildren="true"]")` to `$("td[haschildren='true']")`

Comment: Actually no, sorry for that my code didn't have that error I just missed that when writing the example here at SO.